# Getting "You have to run LaTeX again to get the references right " over and over again

Tags: cross-referencing, compiling, emacs, ubuntu

on Ubuntu 10.04 with Emacs 23.1.1 and TexLive, writing a book (scrbook) spread over different files, I have the following problem: 
Doing C-c C-c in Emacs (the usual cycle LaTeX BibTeX LaTeX LaTeX)
I get 
"You have to run LaTeX again to get the references right"
over and over again, although pdfLaTeX writes the files and there are apparently no references missing in the pdf ( a search for "??" gave 0 results).

Before telling the whole story I would like to ask If anybody experienced this problem before, because I could not find any reports. Is diagnosis and treatment of similar cases available somwhere?

Comment: Can you try to create a MWE (Minimal working example)? Please avoid telling the "whole" story, but rather do some preliminary work: Copy the files to a separate directory, add the files into the main file and check if it still happens. Start removing parts of the file as long as the problem is still happening...once you can reproduce the problem with a file that only contains relevant code, and the problem still persists, post it here....more likely, you'll find the problem in the meantime...but if not, by all means, post it here...

Answer (score 19):

This can happen in rare cases if a reference oscillates which page it is on.  That is, the initial run with unresolved references puts referenced object Foo on page 39, rerunning to fix references adjusts layout so that Foo moves to page 40, and rerunning again moves it back to page 39 (with subsequent reruns toggling it between 39 and 40).

If that what is happening, you'll need to figure out what reference is oscillating and change your document a bit so that its location is stable.

Comment: Hi Micheal, thank you - perfect diagnosis. I took a half page piece of "lorem ipsum" text an copied it successively at the beginning of each chapter of my book. In the 7th out of 10 chapters it did the trick and Latex was done after two runs.

Comment: It turned out that inserting one blank line in a textblock in that chapter (a new paragraph) was suficient to make Latex compile without problems again. I should become a software tester - I always hit that rare cases ;-)