# Footnotes starting at one on each new page in a book-length document

Tags: footnotes

It seems that no matter what I do, the footnotes are not quite right.  On every other page, it might start with 2, with 1 being at the end of the list on the previous page, or similar.  No matter how many times I re-run it, it always tells me to re-run it to fix cross-references.

I have tried `perpage`, `footmisc`, `zref-perpage`, and even the ancient `footnpag`.

This [FAQ](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-rerun) doesn't give me much hope.

The `perpage` package almost works.  It certainly works in small examples but not in a book with 800 pages.

---

EDIT:

Attempt 1:

```tex
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
```

Attempt 2:

```tex
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
```

Attempt 3:

```tex
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote}
```

I'm using the memoir class.  Each page has about 10-40 footnotes.

I'm using lualatex.

The first problematic footnote doesn't appear until page 38.

As [this answer suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/getting-you-have-to-run-latex-again-to-get-the-references-right-over-and-over), the "reference oscillates which page it is on".

---

EDIT 2:

Here is the simplest example.  The issue is present on page 26 where the list of footnotes starts with 34.

https://gist.github.com/honza/8707c5eaeb038aa611a44925e3b4c7bc

Comment: Please provide more information regarding "I have tried `perpage`, `footmisc`, `zref-perpage`". Specifically, which options did you try?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that exhibits your problem.

Comment: More details added!

Comment: you are stressing the system with so many footnotes on a page and near page breaks. The compilation vacillates between `something^1` which fits on a page and `something^34` which has to be broken over two pages as `some-thing34`. It doesn't matter which system you use, you will have to suppress some hyphenation. Try e.g. `\mbox{something\footnote{...}` at the problematic places.

Answer (score 1):

I think with this many footnotes its better to add them at the end of the document. Using `\usepackage{endnotes} \let\footnote=\endnote %` and

```
\clearpage
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

At the end of the document.

If you want translate Notes title to something else use:

`\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Former footnotes}}`

`\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand{\notesname}{σημειώσεις}}`

Here is preamble I used to compile [book.tex](https://gist.github.com/honza/8707c5eaeb038aa611a44925e3b4c7bc) document.

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Gentium}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{PT Sans}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{Gentium}

\ifxetex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=monotonic]{greek}\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[Latin, Greek]{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\defaultfont}{}
\setTransitionsForGreek{\greekfont}{}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\englishfont}{}
\else
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic,english,main=greek]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=el,main]{greek}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{PT Sans}
\fi

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyphsubst}
\usepackage{lettrine}
%\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

%\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Former footnotes}}
%\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand{\notesname}{σημειώσεις}}
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}

\makeatletter % better spacing for endnotes
\def\enoteformat{%
  \rightskip\z@ \leftskip\z@ \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode{\setbox\z@=\lastbox}\llap{\theenmark\enskip}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\hangpara{2em}{1}\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1} \ #2}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\arabic{footnote}}}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\begin{document}
\sloppy
... %% lines 29 to 373 of book.tex
\theendnotes
%% If one want start a new endnote list for next chapter uncomment `setcount` these 
%\setcounter{endnote}{0}
%\newpage
% \chapter*{next chapter}
% \theendnotes
%%
\end{document}
```

If you want endnote list after each chapter one can add `\setcounter{endnote}{0}` after `\theendnotes` and before start of the new chapter.

Comment: The nature of the document demands that the footnotes be placed on the same page. It's a graded reader for students of a foreign language, and those footnotes gloss unfamiliar vocabulary. Having to flip to the end of the book would diminish the book's usefulness.

Comment: Try twiddle with `/newpage` and `/theendnotes` to get text and notes to same page.